# Load Animation From Assets Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm newbie programming Game with Unity Engine. I have searched "How to load animation from assets in unity " But haven't find solution.

I'm handle Trigger of collider

```
void OnTriggerCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll){

     if(coll.gameObject.tag = "Player"){
        //try to load animation

     }

}
```

Help me if you know ! Thanks

Comment: How is the animation saved? As AssetBundle or just prefab? Do you have a screenshot of the Asset?

Comment: First, thanks for reply :). Animation I saved to folder Assets/Animations like file (.anim)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you will have hard time making my solution work because it looks like you lack Unity basic stuff.

`OnTriggerCollisionEnter2D` is not a valid callback function to detect `Trigger`.

`OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)` is what you are looking for.

Secondly, don't anything during onTrigger. Load the animation in the `Start()` function then play it in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function.

Also `if(coll.gameObject.tag = "Player")` should be `if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")`. Notice the double '`=`'. You compare with double '`=`' not one.  but not efficient. If possible, use `coll.gameObject.CompareTag` instead of `coll.gameObject.tag ==`.

Put the Animation in the `Assets/Resources/Animation`  folder

```
Animation animation;
AnimationClip animanClip;
string animName = "walk";

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    //Load Animation
    loadAnimation();
}

void loadAnimation()
{
    GameObject tempObj = Resources.Load("Animations/" + animName, typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;
    if (!tempObj == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Animation NOT found");
    }
    else
    {
        animation = tempObj.GetComponent<Animation>();
        animanClip = animation.clip;

        animation.AddClip(animanClip, animName);
    }
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        animation.Play(animName);
    }
}
```

Finally, study these tutorials.

[Unity Scripting Tutorial](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting)

[Unity Physics Tutorial](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics)

[Other Unity Tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials)

Comment: Why GameObject return null ? I'm enter match name and direction.